# Access a treeview node value from another treeview

Tags: c#, treeview, treeviewitem

I have 2 treeview say treeview1 and treeview2..On clicking a node in treeview1 and then when i click a node in treeview2 i need the node values of the clicked node from both the treeviews to be displayed..?can anyone give me an idea in this task..?

Comment: How do you mean displayed? For example, do you want a dialogue box to appear after selecting a node from tree 1 and a node from tree 2?

Answer (score 4):

You'd do it in exactly the same way for both.

```
private void treeView2_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text + ", " + treeView2.SelectedNode.Text);
}
```